# error in login to database engine with sa

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I install SQL server 2008 developer edition and I connect to it using **Windows Authentication**. But onece to try to connect with **SQL Server Authentication** faced with 233 and then 18456 error code.

user: sa, permission to connect to database engine: Grant, Login: enabled, Enforce Password policy: unchecked

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install SQL Server, by default it only allows "Windows Authentication"

You need to [change this to "Mixed mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)